# How to get player with highest, second highest, etc. score?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make an event for a server. The goal is simple, you have to do as many tasks as possible before the timer runs out. I already figured the timer out.

However, here's the catch. I want to teleport somewhere else the 3 players that have the highest score, the second highest and the third highest. I have a different room for each of them.

I tried at first to teleport the player somewhere if they had completed 20 tasks, somewhere else for 15 and 10. But there may be 3 players that have done 10, 11 and 12 tasks, in that case they would all go into the third room, but I need them to get teleported to different places.

Comment: Minecraft 1.12.2 or 1.13.2?

Comment: Minecraft 1.13.2

Comment: How are you detecting which players get 1st, 2nd or 3rd? Are you using scores?

Comment: @SpiceWeasel I think that's his question.

Comment: @Gothilawn Is your question how to find the player with the highest, second highest, etc. score? If yes, I would edit it a lot to make that more clear.

Comment: @FabianRöling yeah, that my question, I also need to teleport those first, second, third to different locations when the timer run out

Comment: Do you have a way to track what room players are in? Say, by adding a score of 1 to them when they enter a new room?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep the numbers, first copy the scores to a temporary scoreboard, because some will get removed during the calculation. This command copies everyone's score in the scoreboard `tasks` to the scoreboard `temp`:

```
/execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s temp = @s tasks
```

Then you give a dummy player the lowest possible value in that scoreboard. A name starting with `$` cannot occur as a real player name.

```
/scoreboard players set $highest temp -2147483648
```

Here comes the magic: `scoreboard players operation […] >` assigns the higher of two values to the left side, in this case `$highest`'s score in `temp`. By comparing every player's score with $highest this way, you end up with the highest value, because it increases the score of `$highest` every time it encounters a higher value in any of the players' scores.

```
/execute as @a run scoreboard players operation $highest temp > @s temp
```

Now you can do something with a player that has the same score as `$highest` in that scoreboard:

```
/execute as @a if score @s temp = $highest temp run tp @s <coordinates>
```

To get the second player, the third and so on, you just need to repeat that process without the player(s) with the highest value:

```
/execute as @a if score @s temp = $highest temp run scoreboard players reset @s temp
```

Now use commands 2, 3 and 4 again, with a new teleport target.

Comment: Might be a good idea to put all of this into a couple of function files.

Comment: Sure, if you want to do that. It's just those commands without slashes, I would expect everyone who uses functions to be able to do that themselves.

Comment: I was talking more about the glue commands to make this work seamlessly.  Make it a drop-in solution, as it were.

Comment: Since you need to __do something__ with the first, second, etc. player, this would need a modification by the player anyway.

Comment: Thank you Fabian Röling, it works great, my event works now thank you one million times ^^

Comment: @Gothilawn You can use the checkmark icon below the vote buttons to mark it as having solved your problem.

Comment: @FabianRöling Would this work with fake players on the scoreboard too? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 You can try with `*` instead of `@a`. I'm not sure if that works, but it should.

Comment: @FabianRöling, how would this work if not all the players were online? `@a` just targets online players right? Can I do `*[type=player]`?

Comment: So you mean you have online real players, offline real players and fake players on the same scoreboard and want to get the top from all real players? I don't know if you can do that. But when you do your scoreboard stuff, you could always write to two scoreboards, one with and one without fake players. Or just split it up more in general, if you can.