# How to track someone's Y position and make it stop at the highest result and display that result as a number on a scoreboard in minecraft? 1.19

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have `/execute store result score <player> <Scoreboard name> run data get entity <player> Pos[1]` but I don't know how to execute and display the highest score once they player hits the highest possible score. idk if its possible to only track once it gets the highest position but I would love some help because I'm stuck rn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get player with highest, second highest, etc. score?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/347310/how-to-get-player-with-highest-second-highest-etc-score)

Comment: I tihnk the duplicate talks about ranking the scores, rather than keeping track of the score's highest point reached

Comment: @pppery These questions look similar, but upon a second look they are quite distinct. This asker is looking to track the highest number that their score has ever reached, rather than finding the highest score among a set of entities.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a scoreboard with the `Y` value using your `execute store` (scoreboards are more versatile than data) and have another one with the highest score, using the operation `>` on `scoreboard players operation` subcommand

```
/execute as @a store result score @s Y run data get entity @s Pos[1]
/execute as @a run scoreboard players operation @s Ymax > @s Y
```

And to display the score, you can use the simple setdisplay:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebard Ymax
```

Side note: The starting value for Ymax will be empty, but because of the operation, it will end up with 0 if your Y value is bellow 0 (for some odd reason) rather than whatever negavite value of Y you have.